# Excel conditional that is in the same cell as an input

Tags: excel

I am trying to work an excel spread sheet at the moment. Everything is going fine bar for this issue.

I am building a conditional statement  and If I create an extra row and place this formula into it works perfectly.

```
=IF(G2="M","M",IF(G2="m", "M", IF(G2="d", "D", IF(G2="D","D", IF(G2="n", "N", IF(G2="N","N", "O"))))) )
```

What I would like to do is have the input cell and the result's output in the same cell.

Could anyone give me a quick steer in how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Doesn't that create a circular reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as your input would overwrite the formula.

VBA is the way to to go if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the column having the formula, and put the value of formula on next column. For example if your complex formula is on `K` column (let's say `K2`), you just need to hide `K`, and put following on `L2`:

`=K2`

Or, you may protect the sheet/workbook after protecting the formulas, since your idea is to hide the formulas! Just the "Format Cells" dialog, and see Protection tab. Now, you need to search on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Validation with a DropDown and allow D,M,N,O